# TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'datetime.time' in relation with a scatter plot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, typeerror

i have created the following DataFrame: date_merge as an example, because i actually want to display the temperature values throughout the day.

```
df_time = filtered_df_date["longtime"].dt.time
df_date = filtered_df_date["longtime"].dt.date
```

filtered_df_date:

| index | longtime |
| --- | --- |
| 52754 | 2020-01-01 00:00:00 |
| 52755 | 2020-01-01 00:32:00 |
| 52756 | 2020-01-01 00:33:00 |
| ... | ... |
| 53261 | 2020-01-01 23:59:00 |

```
date_merge = pd.merge(df_time, df_date, left_index=True, right_index=True)
date_merge = pd.merge(date_merge, pickd_column_df, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

| index | longtime_time | longtime_date | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 52755 | 00:32:00 | 2020-01-01 | 23.3 |
| 52757 | 00:34:00 | 2020-01-01 | 23.3 |
| 52759 | 00:37:00 | 2020-01-01 | NaN |
| 52760 | 00:38:00 | 2020-01-01 | NaN |
| 52761 | 00:39:00 | 2020-01-01 | naN |
| .... | ... | ... | ... |
| 53261 | 23:59:00 | 2020-01-01 | 23.9 |

now I plot the longtime_date on the x-axis as an example:

```
ax = date_merge.plot(x ="longtime_date" , y="value" , kind="scatter" ,figsize=[15, 5], linewidth=0.1, alpha=0.6, color="#003399")
plt.show()
```

[image]
it works no error.
If I now use longtime_time instead of longtime_date for the x-axis I get the following error message

```
ax = date_merge.plot(x ="longtime_time" , y="value" , kind="scatter" ,figsize=[15, 5], linewidth=0.1, alpha=0.6, color="#003399")
plt.show()
```

> TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'datetime.time'

**some further information:**

```
print(date_merge["longtime_time"].dtype)
```

output:

> object

```
print(date_merge["longtime_date"].dtype)
```

output:

> object

```
print(date_merge["temperature_ers_lite_1_wermser_0_elsys_0"].dtype)
```

output:

> float64

Comment: can you provide the dataset?

Comment: this is unfortunately not possible because I download the data set from a database and prepare it.

Comment: then there's not much I can do as I would need to see what the data looks lik, specifically `date_merge`. When I run this on your sample set above, I cannot reproduce your error. It works fine on my end, so I need to see what's there in the data.

Comment: looks like what you'll need to do is convert your `longtime_time` column from `datetime.time` to `str`

Comment: i can give you the way to the dataframe if this helps: `df_time = filtered_df_date["longtime"].dt.time  ` and `df_date = filtered_df_date["longtime"].dt.date` then i merged two times `date_merge = pd.merge(df_time, df_date, left_index=True, right_index=True)` sencond merge `date_merge = pd.merge(date_merge, pickd_column_df, left_index=True, right_index=True)`

Comment: ya, that could work

Comment: post that in your original post

Comment: i have an additional question. i could also create a scatter plot from the filtered_df_date above. However, the x-axis then shows the date. Would it work that i only show the section with the time on the x_axis ?

Comment: ya, that would work. you could just change the tick lables to only display the time. Give me a few minutes, and I'll add that on to the solution here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so I think the issue is you need to convert that column to `str`.

So at some point before plotting:

```
date_merge['longtime_time'] = date_merge['longtime_time'].astype(str)
ax = date_merge.plot(x ="longtime_time" , y="value" , kind="scatter" ,figsize=[15, 5], linewidth=0.1, alpha=0.6, color="#003399")
plt.show()
```

Or could do:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

date_merge = pd.DataFrame(
[['2020-01-01 00:32:00' ,23.3],
['2020-01-01 00:34:00'      ,23.3],
['2020-01-01 00:37:00'      ,np.nan],
['2020-01-01 00:38:00'      ,np.nan],
['2020-01-01 00:39:00'      ,np.nan],
['2020-01-01 23:59:00'      ,23.9]],
columns = ['longtime'       ,'value'])

date_merge["longtime"] = pd.to_datetime(date_merge["longtime"])

ax = date_merge.plot(x ="longtime" , y="value" , kind="scatter" ,figsize=[15, 5], linewidth=0.1, alpha=0.6, color="#003399")

timeFmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(timeFmt)
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

That `TypeError` arises because *matplotlib* doesn't handle times or timedeltas for the axes. It has to be a complete timestamp (date + optional time) or a numeric value.

A common approach is to:

1. Coerce the time/timedelta values to strings
2. Convert strings into full timestamp objects with an arbitrary date
3. Use a custom date tick formatter to display just time components

You could also avoid expensive string manipulation and do arithmetic on the underlying data types (`datetime64[ns]` → POSIX-equivalent). But since you're already using *pandas*, I'd suggest:

1. Promote the entire timestamp column **longtime** to a `DatetimeIndex`, then
2. Subtract out the date components (e.g. `df.index -= df.index.floor('D')`)

After step 2, the `pd.DataFrame` has a `TimedeltaIndex`. Starting in [v0.20.0](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/15067), *pandas* supports native x-axis tick labels for `TimedeltaIndex` which means you can simply call `.plot()` and obtain a plot like this:

```py
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

idx = pd.date_range('2000-01-01', '2000-01-03T23:00', freq='H')
data = np.random.ranf(len(idx))
df = pd.DataFrame({'once': data, 'twice': data*2}, idx)
df.index -= df.index.floor('D')
df.plot()
```

(Note x-axis labels are automatically formatted, and also they're labeled '0 days' because date components were removed.)

[image: Line plot with time delta x-axis ticks, ten hours apart]

However, you are probably more interested in aggregating by time of day:

```py
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

idx = pd.date_range('2000-01-01', '2000-01-03T23:00', freq='H')
data = np.random.ranf(len(idx))
df = pd.DataFrame({'once': data, 'twice': data*2}, idx)
df.index -= df.index.floor('D')
df.groupby(level=0).mean().plot(rot=45)
```

[image: Line plot with data averaged by time-of-day, using automatic time delta tick labels]

Or in separately plotting individual days:

```py
import pandas as pd, numpy as np, matplotlib.pyplot as plt

idx = pd.date_range('2000-01-01', '2000-01-03T23:00', freq='H')
data = np.random.ranf(len(idx))
df = pd.DataFrame({'once': data, 'twice': data*2}, idx)

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot()

days = df.groupby(lambda ts: ts.dayofyear)
for doy, grp in days:
    grp.index -= grp.index.floor('D')
    grp.rename(columns=lambda s: "{0} ({1})".format(s, doy), inplace=True)
    grp.plot(rot=45, ax=ax1)
```

[image: Line plots of series vs. time of day, grouped by day, with automatic x-axis tick label formatting]

If you're somehow constrained to building plots with *matplotlib*, you can approximate the above functionality with a custom tick formatter (e.g. `pd.Timestamp(x).strftime('%H:%M')`)

```py
import pandas as pd, numpy as np, matplotlib.pyplot as plt

idx = pd.date_range('2000-01-01', '2000-01-03T23:00', freq='H')
data = np.random.ranf(len(idx))
df = pd.DataFrame({'once': data, 'twice': data*2}, idx)
days = df.groupby(lambda ts: ts.dayofyear)

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot()
plt.setp(ax1.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45)
for doy, grp in days:
    grp.index -= grp.index.floor('D')
    ax1.plot(grp.index, grp)
    ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(lambda x,p: pd.Timestamp(x).strftime('%H:%M'))
```

[image: Line plot of series vs. time-of-day, grouped by day, with tick formatters provided by matplotlib]